# Sail.js multiple connections on start

Tags: postgresql, heroku, sails.js, waterline

I've got an odd problem - on start of my sails app (which is connecting with postgres and deployed on heroku ) there are multiple connections (around 10) to database, and since it's free account, if I then try to launch app on localhost to test some new code I get an error "too many connections for a role". So does anyone know why there are so many connections to database and can I change it, to have only one connection per app?

EDIT:
Error creating a connection to Postgresql: error: too many connections for role
"xwoellnkvjcupt"
Error creating a connection to Postgresql: error: too many connections for role
"xwoellnkvjcupt"
error: Hook failed to load: orm (error: too many connections for role "xwoellnkv
jcupt")
error: Error encountered while loading Sails core!
error: error: too many connections for role "xwoellnkvjcupt"
    at Connection.parseE (C:\Studia\szachman2\node_modules\sails-postgresql\node
_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:561:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Studia\szachman2\node_modules\sails-postgresq
l\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:390:17)
    at null. (C:\Studia\szachman2\node_modules\sails-postgresql\node_
modules\pg\lib\connection.js:98:18)
    at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at CleartextStream. (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at _stream_readable.js:401:7
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)

this is an error I am getting often when trying to test some new code on localhost.

Answer (score 5):

@jantar @sgress454 I [just added](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-postgresql/commit/8a1b5d3f405bb50913c3e274d82d2c530c2190c0#diff-a7bcb5fcc46018435e1ce3fa65fcb992R980) a troubleshooting message in `sails-postgresql` to try and make this better.  Here's what it says:

> -> **Maybe your `poolSize` configuration is set too high?** e.g. If your Postgresql database only supports 20 concurrent connections, you should make sure you have your `poolSize` set as something < 20. The default `poolSize` is 10.
>
> To override the default `poolSize`, specify a `poolSize` property on the relevant Postgresql "connection" config object. If you're using Sails, this is generally located in `config/connections.js`, or wherever your environment-specific database configuration is set.
>
> -> **Do you have multiple Sails instances sharing the same Postgresql database?** Each Sails instance may use up to the configured `poolSize` # of connections. Assuming all of the Sails instances are just copies of one another (a reasonable best practice) we can calculate the actual # of Postgresql connections used (C) by multiplying the configured `poolSize` (P) by the number of Sails instances (N). If the actual number of connections (C) exceeds the total # of **AVAILABLE** connections to your Postgresql database (V), then you have problems.  If this applies to you, try reducing your `poolSize` configuration. A reasonable `poolSize` setting would be V/N.

Comment: I have hit the same stage of my sails adventure now. My server should accept 200 connections. I have been able to connect with the sails-postgres adapter before but now hit the connection limit for good. I restart the server, cleared all connections but sails-postgresql does no longer connect to the server. :(

Comment: I can't find a `poolSize` option, is it possible this solution here is correct for sails v1? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54968280/1828637 I have to add `max` key?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Sails's *auto-migration* feature which attempts to keep your models and database synced up.  It's not intended to be used in production.  You can turn auto-migration off on a single model by adding `migrate: safe` to the model definition:

```
module.exports = {
    migrate: 'safe',
    attributes: {...}
}
```

You can turn auto-migration off for *all* models by adding a `model` config, usually in your `config/locals.js`:

```
module.exports = {

    model: {
        migrate: 'safe'
    },
    environment: 'production',
    ...other local config...
}
```

Comment: It still creates 11 connections, this time with queries like this:| SELECT n.nspname as "Schema", c.relname as "Name", CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' END as "Ty
pe", pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner", c2.relname as "Table" FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_index i ON i.indexrelid = c.oid LEFT JOIN pg_cata

Comment: Hmm, those queries are part of Waterline registering the models.  But it shouldn't crash anything.  I'm running two instances of an app on a free Heroku account side-by-side with no issues.  Can you update your question with the log output you're getting?

Comment: It doesn't crash it just doesn't allow to create more connections so next instances can't start properly. Another question I've got it is, is one database connection created for each query, or for each app? Cause if for each query, then I guess this heroku free db wont do for our app, cause it is a chess server, so it will be hard to play few games at the same time. Oh and I will get output log next time it happens to show it here.

Answer (score 1):

A little update for the V1. Your adapter in config/datastore.js should look like this if you want to set a maximum size for the connection pool :

```
{
  adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
  url: 'yourconnectionurl',
  max: 1 // This is the important part for poolSize, I set 1 because I don't want more than 1 connection ^^
}
```

If you want to know all infos you can set, look here : https://github.com/sailshq/machinepack-postgresql/blob/176413efeab90dc5099dc60718e8b520942ce3be/machines/create-manager.js , at line 162 :

```
// Basic:
        'host', 'port', 'database', 'user', 'password', 'ssl',

        // Advanced Client Config:
        'application_name', 'fallback_application_name',

        // General Pool Config:
        'max', 'min', 'refreshIdle', 'idleTimeoutMillis',

        // Advanced Pool Config:
        // These should only be used if you know what you are doing.
        // https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool#documentation
        'name', 'create', 'destroy', 'reapIntervalMillis', 'returnToHead',
        'priorityRange', 'validate', 'validateAsync', 'log'
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I couldn't find where it was changing poolSize. I looked everywhere. It seems it's `max` as you pointed out.