# Sails Postgresql Heroku PoolSize doesnt work

Tags: postgresql, heroku, sails.js

This is my error:
Is your Postgresql configuration correct?  Maybe your `poolSize` configuration is set too high? e.g. If your Postgresql database only supports 20 concurrent connections, you should make sure you have your `poolSize` set as something < 20 (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27387928/486547). The default `poolSize` is 10. To override default settings, specify the desired properties on the relevant Postgresql "connection" config object where the host/port/database/etc. are configured. If you're using Sails, this is generally located in `config/connections.js`, or wherever your environment-specific database configuration is set.

I have change the poolSize but nothing changes. Please can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and switching migrate in config/model -> migrate=safe solved it.